# How to select only one item from a list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to make a list where you can select only one item. Something like a multiple choice question with one answer.

Currently I can select and unselect any item I want.

If I select another item I want the previous item to be unchecked.. Can someone guide me on this? Thanks in advance.

[Here's an image of selecting any item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRxd.png)

This is the code for each items:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CheckBox } from "react-native-elements";

const ListItem = ({ title }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  return (
    <CheckBox
      title={title}
      checkedIcon="check-circle"
      uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
      checkedColor="#46A522"
      uncheckedColor="black"
      checked={state}
      onPress={() => setState(!state)}
    />
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

Edit: Parent component:

```
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import ListItem from "../components/ListItem";

const SelectFromTo = ({ navigation }) => {
  const arr = [
    { name: "Abdulpur" },
    { name: "Accalpur" },
    { name: "Ahasanganj" },
    { name: "Akhaura" },
    { name: "Banani" },
    { name: "Chandpur" },
    { name: "Pabna" },
  ];
  return (
    <View>
      <Header title={"Ticket Purchase"} />
      <FlatList
        data={arr}
        keyExtractor={(data) => data.name}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem title={item.name} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SelectFromTo;
```

Comment: Can you share the parent component, you should maintain the selected item in the parent component and render based on the prop you get

Comment: Edited.. added the parent component.

Comment: The screenshot you provide it's what you want to achieve?or it's wrong way?

Comment: it's the wrong way. i just want one selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep selection state in the list components.

Something like this:

```
const SelectFromTo = () => {
  // It can be index/id/name
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  // ...

   renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem title={item.name} checked={item.name === selectedItem} onPress={() => setSelectedItem(item.name)} />}
}
```

and in `ListItem`

```
const ListItem = ({ title, checked, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <CheckBox
      // ...
      checked={checked}
      onPress={onPress}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe prefere to use [radio buttons](https://www.positronx.io/create-radio-button-component-in-react-native/)

Or if you want to do this width checkboxes, the container element of your listItems must handle the state of all your items. You can take ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732864/checkboxes-getting-starting-value-from-state/63732963#63732963)

Then before to set the active checkbox, reset all width a map function.